# problema con Application.Exit() vb 2005

Tags: vb6, vb, windows-mobile

Estoy intentando manejar el tema de la desconexión en mi aplicación para una Hand Held con Windows Ce v5 en Visual Basic 2005. lo estoy tratando en un modulo de rutinas, el cual me verifica el estatus de la conexión. Si esta conexión se encuentra cerrada, se le informa a el usuario y se inicia un proceso de re conexión; una vez concluido dicho proceso, se manda a cerrar la aplicacion, pero la instrucción **Application.Exit()** no termina la aplicación. Aquí mi código:

Método en rutinas:

```
Public Sub fbReconecta()
    Dim x As Integer
    If ConSql.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        If ConSql.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            If MsgBox("Se esta recuperando la conexión, si esta demorando ud. puede cerrar la " & _
            " aplicación. ¿Desea Cerrarla?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbNo Then
                For x = 0 To 20
                    BDAbrir(ConSql, , PServidorDB, PBaseDatos, PUserDB, PUserPwdDB)
                Next
                If ConSql.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    MsgBox("No se pudo recuperar la conexión, la aplicación se cerrará", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Atención")
                    Application.Exit()
                End If
            Else
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Llamada a Metodo

```
Catch ex As Exception
    sqldata.Close()
    fbReconecta()
    If ConSql.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
       Application.Exit()
    Else
       GoTo Reintenta
    End If
End Try
```

Si tuvieran alguna idea de como resolver la cuestión de que se cierre la aplicación y que cancele las otras instrucciones, se los agradecería demasiado

Comment: No has probado con un `End` común?

Comment: Si, ya lo intenté. Pero VB2005 no cuenta con método End.